NullInjectorError: No provider for _CdkConnectedOverlay when Upgrading Angular 16 => 17
Just trying to upgrade to Angular v17 and it seems ng-zorro-antd elements aren't loading.

Check your versions. It looks like a mismatch between Angular CDK and ng-zorro is causing this issue. ~17.3.10 != 17.4
You should also ensure you include @angular/cdk as a dependency in your application if it needs to load ng-zorro elements.
npm install --save @angular/cdk@17

